# How to integrate $\int \frac{1}{x^6-1}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate
$$\int \frac{1}{x^6-1}dx$$
I have done it by using
$$x^6-1=(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$
and then applying partial fraction decomposition but this makes for a very long process.

Is there a better way to integrate this function?

Comment: See [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1158009p5500997).

Comment: What about partial fraction decomposition over complex numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decompose the integrand as
$$\frac2{x^6-1}= \frac1{x^2-1}- \frac{x^2}{x^6-1}-\frac{x^2+1}{x^4+x^2+1}
$$
and then integrate piecewise to obtain

\begin{align}
&\int \frac{1}{x^6-1}dx\\
=&\ \frac12\int \frac1{x^2-1}- \frac{x^2}{x^6-1}-\frac{x^2+1}{x^4+x^2+1}\ dx\\
 =&\ \frac12\int \frac{dx}{x^2-1}- \frac{\frac13 d(x^3)}{(x^3)^2-1}-\frac{d(x-\frac1x)}{(x-\frac1x)^2+3}\\ =&\ \frac14\ln\frac{x-1}{x+1}-\frac1{12}\ln\frac{x^3-1}{x^3+1}-\frac1{2\sqrt3}\tan^{-1}\frac{x-\frac1x}{\sqrt3}
+C
\end{align}

Comment: There is a typo here $
\int \frac{1}{x^6-1}dx=\frac12\int \frac1{x^3-1}-\frac1{x^3-1}\ dx$- it should be $
\int \frac{1}{x^6-1}dx=\frac12\int \frac1{x^3-1}-\frac1{x^3+1}\ dx$

Comment: Something's wrong... $\frac1{x^3-1}-\frac1{x^3-1}=0$

Comment: @VinanthSBharadwaj thanks